# Loop through all checkboxes in xaml and compose string from their content

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, checkbox

I am looping through all checkboxes with this code.

```
string where = string.Empty;

foreach (CheckBox c in gridApi.Children.OfType<CheckBox>())
{
    if (c.IsChecked == true)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(where += "CategoryMulti like '%" + c.Content.ToString() + "%'");
    }
}
```

From these checkboxes I would like to build one string (*where* variable) for SQL command:

> select telephone from Contacts where CategoryMulti like '%1%'

Problem is that I need to have *or* between sql like tags like this

> select telephone from Contacts where CategoryMulti like '%1%' or CategoryMulti like'%2%'

I need to tell the program how to behave with or adding. For example sql command can't end with or

> select telephone from Contacts where CategoryMulti like '%1%' or CategoryMulti like'%2%' or

Because sql command would end with error. Could you help me how can I build something like that?

I had an idea to leave *OR* for each checked checkbox and get last checked checkbox position in array and remove last 2 characters.

This would work I guess because every checked checkbox gonna add same amount of characters into the *where* variable no matter what. Problem is that I have no idea how to add all checkboxes into array in this loop.. Thank you for any idea.

.xaml

> ```
> <CheckBox Content="cul" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" x:Name="chkBoxCul" Margin="325,59,0,0"/>
> <CheckBox Content="inf" Visibility="Visible" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" x:Name="chkBoxInfo" Margin="408,59,0,0"/>
> <CheckBox Content="spo" Visibility="Visible" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" x:Name="chkBoxSp" Margin="479,56,0,0"/>
> <CheckBox Content="war" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" x:Name="chkBoxWar" Margin="540,56,0,0"/>
> ```

Comment: You should consider learning the MVVM pattern to make use of WPFs abilities. It will make your life a lot easier in the future. WPF is not supposed to be used like WInForms was...
Regarding your question: you can "add" strings to each other like this: `string myString = "TestString";  string output = "testText" + myString;` The result will be output = "testTextTestString"

Comment: @Cabry: Did you consider to use the `Trim` method to remove the trailing "or"? `query = query.TrimEnd(new char[] { ' ', 'o', 'r' });`

Comment: store your conditions in a `var conditions = new List<string>()`, inside foreach loop you may `conditions.Add($"CategoryMulti like '%{c.Content}%'")`, then finally use `var query = string.Join(" OR ", conditions)`

Answer (score 1):

One simple solution would be to add the where expressions in a `List<string>`. 
Then, you can use `string.Join(" or ", yourList);`

An example:

```
var list = new List<string>
{
    "Asd",
    "Qwe",
    "Zxc"
};

var result = string.Join(" OR ",list);
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Result from the example will be: "Asd OR Qwe OR Zxc"

Answer (score 1):

I would approche this using **[String.Join](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join)**. You could for example add all the `CategoryMulti like '%1%'`s for your Checkboxes into a list and then use String.Join like this:

```cs
var list = new List<string>();

foreach (CheckBox c in gridApi.Children.OfType<CheckBox>())
{

    if (c.IsChecked == true)
    {
        list.Add("CategoryMulti like '%" + c.Content.ToString() + "%'");
    }
}

var result = string.Join(" or ", list);
```

`result` now contains `CategoryMulti like '%1%' or CategoryMulti like'%2%' or ...`. But if we now also add LINQ to the mix we can even simplify this to:

```cs
var result = string.Join(" or ", gridApi.Children
    .OfType<CheckBox>()
    .Where(c => c.IsChecked == true)
    .Select(c => "CategoryMulti like '%" + c.Content.ToString() + "%'"));
```

Comment: I did not manage to get the second code to work but the first one works perfectly. One more question maybe, is it also possible to do the same with listview? What if I wanted dynamically add checkbox for each category in CategoryMulti?

Comment: Basically what I mean is. foreach (category in categorymulti) {new checkbox into listview, checbox.name = category}. How do I make these checkboxes arranged in ListView and make the same with original foreach loop. edit: I manage to make this: _foreach (var item in list1.Items)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(item.ToString());
}_
But now I do not know how to make the same. I only get if item is true / false, but how do I make the condition _if item.ischecked = true_ now? @rain336

Comment: Shouldn't you just be able to set `IsChecked` to `true`. Like `item.IsChecked = true;`

Comment: i had it bad in foreach variable. It should be foreach(checkbox item in list1.Items) instead of var item. Sorry